# How to access CloudControl config.free CONFIG_VARS

Tags: cloudcontrol

How to access CloudControl config.free CONFIG_VARS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is not documented well here comes the answer:

```
if ($credFile = getenv('CRED_FILE')) {
    $credFileContents = file_get_contents($credFile);
    if ($credFileContents !== false) {
        $credData = json_decode($credFileContents, true);
        $value = $credData['CONFIG']['CONFIG_VARS']['MY_VAR'];
    }
}
```

That means within `CRED_FILE` the config addon has its corresponding array/secction `CONFIG` which contains another array/section `CONFIG_VARS` which then contains your vars.

Comment: The relevant documentation site is https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Guides/PHP/Add-on%20credentials, but your code is essentially the same.

Comment: Thank you for referencing! Maybe this could be linked in https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Add-on%20Documentation/Deployment/Custom%20Config